# Can a weak entity be involved in both identifying and non-identifying relationships with other tables?

Tags: database, weak-entity, identifying-relationship

Obviously a weak entity must be involved (as the child) in one or more identifying relationships, otherwise it would not be weak.

But can it, at the same time, also be the child in a non-identifying relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, weak entity sets can participate in non-identifying relationships with other *entities*. By "child", I suppose you mean relationships in which the weak entity set is on the determining (many) side of the relationship. There is no restriction on the kinds of relationships in which weak entity sets may participate.

However, watch out for multiple identifying relationships. While a weak entity set can easily be the descendant of a chain of identifying relationships, multiple independent identifying relationships on the same weak entity set are unusual, and challenges the very notion of an entity set. See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894299/relationship-in-er-model/42908246#42908246).

Note that your question title mentions relationships between tables, which confuses conceptual (ER) and physical (tabular) models. Entity relations are represented by tables, but so are relationship relations in general (only one-to-one and one-to-many relationships can be denormalized into the entity relation of a/the determining entity set, many-to-many and ternary and higher relationships still require their own tables).